# Formatting Puzzle!

Tags: lateral-thinking

This puzzle works best if you **do not look in edit.** If you do, please refrain from posting answers.

So basically the idea is to count how many squares/rectangles this post includes.

*Don't underestimate the ability of this being a puzzle.*

> 

> 

Comment: See?  Zero net votes so far.  I +1ed, I swear it!  It was simply **too** brilliant a puzzle.  I can empathize, as, I, too, am often too brilliant.  (Sweet, set a new record for consecutive commas.  Someone call Guiness!)

Comment: @tjbtech Lol it's fine :P

Comment: On 2nd thought, why do people hate this? XD

Comment: I am endlessly amazed as I discover the dichotomy on this site between ragular people, lookin' to have a good time solving puzzles, and bitter malcontents, bent on establishing a vacuum of darkness, melancholy, and hate.  OK, so it's a bit of hyperbole.  And it's still the interwebz in the end.  But for a site specializing in fun and games, it sure seems like a select number obsess over how to ensure the status quo remains as sober and unhappy as possible.  It's truly tiring and not a great way to draw newcomers or keep those you've got.  Get a sense of humor, ya squares!!

Comment: @tjbtech A really good way to dissuade someone from coming here is have them stare at a puzzle for hours trying to figure it out, then realize the whole thing wasn't really *clever* at all. But honestly, I have no idea what this one was meant to be, even with the "answers" below. I don't know if it was clever or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is actually no unique answer!

> It depends on the device you use to look at the posting. Checking the site with my iphone via web is rendered differently from web by PC is differently from iPad app... Most notably the 'citation' block are rendered differently.

Comment: What would I have gained from watching the edit? I assume I am now allowed to do so?

Comment: Oh nos!  Now, _that's_ some tricksy nonsense right there!  Regular voodoo black magic.  Well played, sir.  And definitely fine work on @warspyking's part, no matter the "right" answer.  Some are gonna hate all over his guts for this one.

Comment: @Bmy Nothing. Merely a red herring XD

Comment: @tjbtech I have no doubt that you are right. People just stating at their screen counting, then they see the trick I pulled off on them.

Comment: Sorry Victor XD

Answer (score 2):

I did not looked at the edit, nor cheated with anything similar. Just fixed the eyes in the question as show and counted.

> I counted 130 white boxes.
>  
>  If you count the quoting blocks, then this is 132.
>  
>  If you count the two tags, the OP's box and the OP's avatar, add more 4.
>  
>  You may consider that each quote box is a pair of rectangles, one of them tall, thin and yellow and the big one is pink. The yellow and pink rectangles combined forms another larger rectangle also. So three rectangles for each quote box. Totalizing more 6 rectangles here (two quote boxes).
>  
>  In the end this could be 140.

Thanks to @tjbtech for a suggestion. :)

Comment: You really counted them all? Did you double check?

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly:

> 1 square and 7 rectangles.

Just that!? Why!?

> The boxes are not rectangles, because they have rounded corners. The same for the tags marks. No letter possesses rectangular parts.
>  
>  The quote boxes are a pair of rectangles each one. A yellow thin and tall rectangle and a big pink one each. The pink and yellow rectangle are also a rectangle when combined. There are two quote boxes, so 6 rectangles with that.
>  
>  The OP's box is a rectangle. The OP's avatar is a square.

Thanks to @tjbtech for a suggestion. :)

Comment: What about the (two) combinations of smaller rectangles into bigger ones?  No?

Comment: @tjbtech Post that if you think so.

Comment: Nah, wouldn't be right to post an answer based on yours.  I take it, you disagree with my comment..?

Comment: @tjbtech No, I don't disagree, just thought that if the idea is yours, so you should post it. But since you don't, I will update this. :)

Comment: Still, which answer is _more_ right?  @Victor obviously saw rounded edges when counting.  And the question seems to prompt for an actual number.  Ohhhhhhh!  I get it now.  The **real** puzzle is figuring out which answer to accept.  It was warspyking's devious plan to puzzle **himself** all along!!1!!!2!

Comment: That, or the answer is actually 42.